# angular 2 app not working in ie/edge

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I'm not undestand why app not working. app work good in chrome and firefox.     ie/edge  doesn't show date. it's default tutorial angular 2 app without modifications.Sorry for my english.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>My First Angular App</h1>

    <button (click)="showCurrentMonth()">Show Month</button>
    <span *ngIf="curentMonth">{{curentMonth}}</span>
    <br/>
    <button (click)="showCurrentcurentDate()">Show Date</button>
    <span *ngIf="curentDate">{{curentDate}}</span>
    `
})
```

.

```
export class AppComponent {
  splitedDate: string[] = new Date().toLocaleDateString().split(".");
  curentMonth: string;
  curentDate: Date;
  months = [
    "January","February","March","April",
    "May","June","July","August",
    "September","October","November","December"
  ]
  showCurrentMonth() {
    // udefined in IE/Edge
    this.curentMonth = this.months[parseInt(this.splitedDate[1]) - 1] 
  }
  showCurrentcurentDate() {
    var splitedcurrentDate: number[] = new Date()
       .toLocaleDateString()
       .split(".")
       .map(d => parseInt(d, 10))
    // invalid Date in IE/Edge
    this.curentDate = new Date(splitedcurrentDate[2], splitedcurrentDate[1],  splitedcurrentDate[0]) 
   }
}
```

ts.config

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "~2.0.2",
"@angular/compiler": "~2.0.2",
"@angular/core": "~2.0.2",
"@angular/forms": "~2.0.2",
"@angular/http": "~2.0.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~2.0.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.0.2",
"@angular/router": "~3.0.2",
"@angular/upgrade": "~2.0.2",
"angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.5",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"systemjs": "0.19.39",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"zone.js": "^0.6.25"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
  "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
  "typescript": "^2.0.3",
  "typings": "^1.4.0",

"canonical-path": "0.0.2",
"http-server": "^0.9.0",
"tslint": "^3.15.1",
"lodash": "^4.16.2",
"jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
"karma": "^1.3.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
"karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
"karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.3.4",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "^3.3.0",
"rimraf": "^2.5.4"
},
"repository": {}
```

Comment: I believe you need to check `new Date().toLocaleDateString()` and instead of `.` it should be `/`

Comment: array correctly. he consist from three part of date. [09,10, 2016]